# SQL Merge to Update table with changed history

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, scd2

I have been tasked with building a history table in SQL. I have already built the base table which contains multiple left joins amongst other things. The base table will need to be compared to another table and only update specific columns that have changed, insert new rows where the key doesn't match.

Previously I have used other ETL tools which have GUI style built in SCD loaders, but I don't have such luxury in SQL Server. Here the merge statement can handle such operations. I have used the `MERGE` statement before, but I become a bit stuck when handling flags and date fields based on the operation performed.

Here is the BASE table

| KEY | CLIENT | QUANTITY | CONTRACT_NO | FC_COUNT | DELETE_FLAG | RECORD_UPDATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | A | 1000 | 5015 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |
| 346 | B | 2000 | 9352 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |
| 347 | C | 3000 | 6903 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |
| 348 | D | 1000 | 7085 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |
| 349 | E | 1000 | 8488 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |
| 350 | F | 500 | 6254 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |

Here is the table I plan to merge with

| KEY | CLIENT | QUANTITY | CONTRACT_NO | FC_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | A | 1299 | 5015 | 1 |
| 346 | B | 2011 | 9352 | 1 |
| 351 | Z | 5987 | 5541 | 1 |

The results I'm looking for are

| KEY | CLIENT | QUANTITY | CONTRACT_NO | FC_COUNT | DELETE_FLAG | RECORD_UPDATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | A | 1000 | 5015 | 1 | N | 06/07/2022 |
| 345 | A | 1299 | 5015 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |
| 346 | B | 2000 | 9352 | 1 | N | 06/07/2022 |
| 346 | B | 2011 | 9352 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |
| 347 | C | 3000 | 6903 | 1 | Y | 06/07/2022 |
| 348 | D | 1000 | 7085 | 1 | Y | 06/07/2022 |
| 349 | E | 1000 | 8488 | 1 | Y | 06/07/2022 |
| 350 | F | 500 | 6254 | 1 | Y | 06/07/2022 |
| 351 | Z | 5987 | 5541 | 1 | N | 31/12/9999 |

As we can see I have shown the changes, closed off the old records, marked with a date and a delete flag if they are missing but was there previous, as well as new new row with the new key and data

Would this be a `MERGE`? Some direction on how to perform this sort of operation would be a great help. We have a lot of tables where we need to keep change history and this will help a lot going forward.

code shell attempt

```
SELECT      
            MAIN_KEY,
            CLIENT,
            QUANTITY,
            CONTRACT_NO,
            1 AS FC_COUNT,
            NULL as DELETE_FLG_DD,
            GETDATE() as RECORD_UPDATED_DATE
INTO  #G1_DELTA
FROM
            [dwh].STG_DTL
MERGE [dwh].[PRJ1_DELTA] TARGET
USING #G1_DELTA SOURCE
ON   TARGET.MAIN_KEY                    = SOURCE.MAIN_KEY
    
WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT 
    (
        MAIN_KEY,
        CLIENT,
        QUANTITY,
        CONTRACT_NO,
        FC_COUNT,
        DELETE_FLG_DD,
        RECORD_UPDATED_DATE
    )
VALUES
    (
        SOURCE.MAIN_KEY,
        SOURCE.CLIENT,
        SOURCE.QUANTITY,
        SOURCE.CONTRACT_NO,
        SOURCE.FC_COUNT,
        SOURCE.DELETE_FLG_DD,
        SOURCE.RECORD_UPDATED_DATE
        )
```

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: sure - i have had to provide you with dummy tables, but based on the dummy data here is the shell code i had, again, i'm struggling with how to apply the update rules and change the flags

Comment: code added above

Comment: where does row 2 inside the output table come from? No record like that is found in your input tables, how should that be crafted? Same happens with row 4.

Comment: Apologies, i will amend the tables - i was rushing to get a example together

Comment: I have amended the table, i had the wrong client number - the only change fields we are interested in is the QUANTITY

Comment: If I get it right, all the old date values from the first table get mapped to current day (or is it a specific day?) and the newly added rows will have date corresponding to `31/12/9999`, is that correct? @teelove

Comment: thats correct - if there is a change, the old rows get closed off with todays date, the changed rows (matched key) get inserted and have an open date as you said `31/12/9999`, and the deleted rows  (mathced key but missing) stay in the table, delete flag as Y and a closed of date too. new rows like KEY-351 get inserted and have an open date `31/12/9999`

Comment: do you need a `SELECT` statement or are you looking for a trigger that works on your `INSERT` statements?

Comment: At this point, i'm out of ideas - i'm not sure what a trigger is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to build a history table containing the updated information from your two tables, you first need to select updated information from your two tables.

The changes that need to be applied to your tables are on:

- "*tab1.[DELETE_FLAG]*", that should be updated to `'Y'` whenever it has a match with tab2
- "*tab1.[RECORD_UPDATED_DATE]*", that should be updated to the current date
- "*tab2.[DELETE_FLAG]*", missing and that should be initialized to `N`
- "*tab2.[RECORD_UPDATED_DATE]*", missing and that should be initialized to your random date `9999-12-31`.

Once these changes are made, you can apply the `UNION ALL` to get the rows from your two tables together.

Then, in order to generate a table, you can use a cte to select the output result set and use the `INTO <table>` clause after a selection to generate your "*history*" table.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tab1.[KEY],
           tab1.[CLIENT],
           tab1.[QUANTITY],
           tab1.[CONTRACT_NO],
           tab1.[FC_COUNT],
           CASE WHEN tab2.[KEY] IS NOT NULL
                THEN 'N'
                ELSE 'Y'
           END       AS [DELETE_FLAG],
           CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS [RECORD_UPDATED_DATE]
    FROM      tab1
    LEFT JOIN tab2
           ON tab1.[KEY] = tab2.[KEY] 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT *, 
           'N'          AS [DELETE_FLAG],
           '9999-12-31' AS [RECORD_UPDATED_DATE]
    FROM tab2
)
SELECT *
INTO history
FROM cte
ORDER BY [KEY];
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb05cf6150fc159273bc303081b00312).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input - i will take some time to digest this - i can see from the demo the outputs look great, but i'm going to do my best to study this. thank you again!

Comment: i have just run into an issue where my key is made up of 3 fields, so i assume i can add those with AND to the CASE WHEN ad LEFT JOINS?

Comment: Inside the `CASE` statement it is sufficient for a single field key to be there, as they will be all three null. For the `LEFT JOIN`, you are forced to match all three keys, so an `AND` operator will be needed twice, yes.

Comment: is there anything i need to do settings wise, SQL is not like `cte`

Comment: If you can update your post to include the three keys, I can show directly.

Comment: I've managed to add the keys and copied the fiddle to a test db, and it looks like it will work great but our DBA says we cannot use cte, this will require some working around red tape *sad face* - looks like i will have to have a look into the merge method - i have marked as answered, but i will need to look further into using merge as i dont know how long enable (or whatever it entails) `cte` will take

Comment: If you can't use the ctes and you're forced to use the `MERGE` statement, then using the answered mark or not is up to you, as this answer doesn't satisfy the `MERGE` requirement.

Comment: thank you for you're help, much appreciated - doesnt look like i can use `cte` any time soon

Comment: great news, cte are enabled and the code works :)

Comment: though this fully solves my problem, there is one refinement i could ask you about, the `SELECT * INTO` in the `cte` - this only seems to work when creating a new table with the history, when i load more changes in to tab2 and re-run, it errors saying there is an object already named "history"

Comment: Use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history;` before you rerun this query. You can also add this command on top of the script, so that every time you run it won't prompt you.

Comment: Just to add to this - Its finally come to the point where people have listened to the Dev team, and have after back to the drawing board for a more robust approach, we are adopting a standard SCD2 model, leveraging BigQuery and its Farm Fingerprint function. this mixed with Joins and Merges is far more efficient and less expensive. Thanks for everyone's input.